# Codeigniter get_filename ordering by name

Tags: php, codeigniter, directory, helper

I am getting a directory listing in codeigniter to be published in a form but can't order it.

Is there anyway I can sort it by alphabet? This is the code below and I have gone through documentation but couldn't find anything.

```
    $this->load->helper('directory');
    $list_movs = get_filenames('./spots');
    foreach($list_movs as $mov):

        $movs[$mov] = $mov; 

    endforeach;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$list_movs` is just a `regular array`. You can just sort it using `sort($list_movs)`

If you want to sort in natural order, case insensitive then do:

```
sort($list_movs, SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE);
```

This is the same as using `natcasesort()`, bear in mind that the key-value associations are not retained, but for your usecase I do not suppose it will matter.

If key-value association is important use `asort()`

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not using a any database to use sort, can you please provide some more info about it?

Comment: There is no database involved in this. The sort function just takes an array and sorts its elements

Comment: No it didn't - I'm working on it and will answer when I have result

Comment: If you paste the whole code that you tried as an update to your question, it would be easier